# QT Json парсинг

Tags: json, qt5

Помогите распарсить файл Json.

```
Структура:

  {
"message":
    { "email":["Ошибка поля."],
      "name":["Ошибка поля."],
      "password":["Ошибка поля."],
     },
      "status":"error
  }
```

Пробовал получить данные как QJsonArray, но ругается - это не массив. Попробовал QVariantMap, но там структура получается

```
("message", QVariant(QVariantMap, QMap(("email", QVariant(QVariantList, (QVariant(QString, "Ошибка поля."))))
```

Пример кода, как я пытался получить массив

```
if(reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
        {
            QByteArray buffer = reply->readAll();
            auto doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(buffer);
            QJsonObject jobj = doc.object();
            QJsonArray jarr =jobj["email"].toArray();
            foreach(const QJsonValue &val, jarr)
            {
                QJsonObject obj = val.toObject();
                qDebug() << obj;
            }
```

Ничего не получилось, пустая строка. Подскажите как правильно сделать.

Comment: `message` это не массив, это объект. Его поля — массивы, каждый из которых состоит из одного элемента.

Comment: Как получить эти поля?  Я пробовал вот так, ничего не получилось
            QJsonArray jarr =jobj["email"].toArray();
            foreach(const QJsonValue &val, jarr)
            {
                QJsonObject obj = val.toObject();
                qDebug() << obj 
            }

Comment: Тогда приводите в тексте вопроса полностью воспроизводимый пример, с минимальным количеством кода.

Comment: Добавил пример кода

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот это:

```
auto doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(buffer);
```

Даёт основной JSON объект верхнего уровня. `"message"` является полем этого объекта (как и `"status"`) и, в свою очередь, тоже является JSON объектом. А вот его поля уже являются массивами. Т.е. в Вашем коде Вы сначала должны извлечь объект `message`, а уже потом обращаться к его полям.

Comment: Спасибо! 
Сделал вот так. Это верно? или есть ещё способ? 

           ` auto ff =  jobj["message"].toObject();
            QJsonArray _email = ff["email"].toArray();
            QJsonArray _name = ff["name"].toArray();
            QJsonArray _passwd = ff["password"].toArray();
            QJsonArray _phone = ff["phone"].toArray();`
и получение _email.takeAt(0).toString() и т.д

Comment: @Renovacio, ну это нормальный способ. Многословный — да, но это C++.